# How to upload csv file using php into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fgetcsv

How to upload csv file using php into mysql database correctly?

I have a column (uploaded, column name) in phpmyadmin, in this column will store the uploaded csv file.

I have a little script of uploading csv file into mysql database, but I'm getting some error "404: File Not Found" after I clicked the submit button and the csv file is not saving in the database.

Here the php file with html:

```
<?php
include "dbase.php"; //Connect to Database
$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE contracts"; //empty the table of its current records
 mysql_query($deleterecords);
//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
}
//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $import="INSERT into contracts(uploaded) values('$data[0],$data[1]')";
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
fclose($handle);
echo "Import done";
//view upload form
}else {
echo "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";
echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";
echo "File name to import:<br />\n";
echo "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
 }
?>
```

Database connection:

```
 <?
 $filename=$_POST['filename'];
 $db=mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', '3306')
 or die(mysql_error());
 if(!$db) 
die("no db");
if(!mysql_select_db("databasename",$db))
die("No database selected.");
?>
```

Comment: why dont you store the file on your server then read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script file is named not `upload.php`, that is why you are getting "Not Found" error.

Comment: See. I change it, but when I click the upload it returns blank page and still the csv is not saving in the database

Comment: @User014019 There is may be some error happening. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors');` on top of your script and execute it again. If there are any errors, you will see them.

Comment: I add that little code on top, still im getting this 404: File Not Found after I upload

Comment: @User014019 What was the problem?

Comment: but how can I remove this in result "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Comment: You need to define this field in database as auto_increment, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script that has worked for me before: http://coyotelab.org/php/upload-csv-and-insert-into-database-using-phpmysql.html

Comment: I already see that and tested, unfortunately its not working with me

Comment: The csv is not saving in the database